# Python | Eigenvector components corresponding to their original rows and columns

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra

I hope this isn't a bad question, but I am computing eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix, lets call it A.

A is say 10x10.

I want to get the eigenvector corresponding to its 2nd largest eigenvalue. I do

```
[D, V] = scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs(L, 2)
s = V[:, 0] # this is the 2nd eigenvecotr
```

Now, I want to do some calculations based on comparing certain elements in 's' to some other number. For example:

```
for i in range(0, len(s)):
if s[0] > some number: 
do something with the first column/row (if this was a graph, the first node) in A
```

My questions are:

1. Does it matter if I use scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs, or scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh? I saw documentation online for both, but can't discern the difference.
2. Do the elements in the eigenvector correspond to their original rows/columns? For example s[0] corresponds to the eigenvector of first column/row of A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html) are pretty clear on the row/column question:

> The column v[:, i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i]

The difference between eigs and eigsh is that the latter assumes a symmetric/hermitian matrix.

Finally, for a 10x10 matrix you don't need anything sparse, you're better off just using functions from scipy.linalg.

Comment: I know each eigenvector corresponds to that eigenvalue. I meant, does each entry in the eigenvector correspond to a certain row/column in the original matrix.

If the original matrix represents a graph, then does v[i] (eigenvector ith entry) correspond to the ith node?

Comment: Yes, they satisfy the eigenvalue equation A.dot(v[:,j]) = w[j]*v[:,j].